# How to solve "Unable to load theme by specified key: 'rwd\/astra'","1":"#0 error in magento2?

Tags: migration, themes, database-migration

I migrate magento1 database to magento2 and when I open magento2 frontend and backend than this error occurs.

> "Unable to load theme by specified key: 'rwd/astra'","1":"#0

I have no custom module or theme in magento2 then why this error is produced?

**Does anyone have a solution for this problem?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to records in the design_change table pointing to now non-existent records (as mentioned in Wolf's answer), I also found records in the cms_page table referring to a non-existent theme.

The following query clears the custom_theme values for all cms_page entries.  Please checkout the data in your table before running this query since it will clear all the values -- In my case this is just what I wanted.

UPDATE cms_page SET custom_theme = NULL WHERE custom_theme IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database, in table "design_change" delete row has "design" value same error.

Comment: This is a very messy explanation. Could you split it into steps, and possibly provide some documentation for this?

Comment: My old magento 1 site use athlete/default theme. After migrate to magento 2, in frontend show error "Unable to load theme by specified key: athlete/default". I had delete 2 rows in design_change table http://prntscr.com/i5u5nd